# SQL Server Upgrade Causes Temporary Table Duplication

Tags: sql-server

My company has a legacy system that has run into a problem. The code is a combination of VB6, C# and SQL where the SQL consists of thousands of lines of in-line SQL pasted into a 'C#' application. Many temporary tables are created (and dropped). Finding the position in the code where a temporary table might be created or re-used is not easy (to say the least).

When run using SQL Server 2008 R2 the code behaves as expected. However, when running SQL Server 2014 or SQL Server 2016 one gets the error "There is already an object named '#whatever' in the database."

On the SQL Server 2014 database the compatability level on the database has been set as SQL Server 2008(100) and the MAX DOP (which I suspected to be the possibe source of the problem) has been set to 1.

Is there anyone who has experienced something similiar and if so is there any known workaround. The system is 25 years old and we want to retire the system, but there are those who simply love it too much.

Comment: Try running an Extended Events trace to capture the error and context. That should identify the problem SQL. MAXDOP is not relevant as the same session is used for all threads of the query.

Comment: How is the SQL code being called? Does it go through some custom database wrapper code?  or using SqlConnection/SqlCommand notation?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually amusing and simple. The developers used this function:

`public static bool TemporaryTableExists(string TempTableNameWithHash, DataConnection mDataConnection)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(mDataConnection.GetValueFromSelect(string.Format("SELECT COALESCE(OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.{0}'),0)", TempTableNameWithHash))) > 0;
        }`

The problem is the > 0. In SQL Server 2014 it seems that OBJECT_ID returns a negative value for a temporary table.